# Rotating image does not resize properly using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, rotation

I have an outer div with a width of 200px that has the image inside it having a width of 100%.
Now if I want to rotate that image by 90 deg, its dimensions are not rotated and I cannot set the width to 100%.

```html
<style>
  .rotate {
    rotate: 90deg;
    transform-origin: top left;
    translate: 200px 0px;
  }
</style>
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue;width: 200px; overflow:hidden">
    <img class="" width="100%" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/840/200/300.jpg?hmac=Z8Mc1xk7GaQHQ1hkPTK4cY0dYIxDKGBCHrgyaDqE0u0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div style="border: 1px solid blue;width: 200px; overflow:hidden">
    <img class="rotate" width="100%" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/840/200/300.jpg?hmac=Z8Mc1xk7GaQHQ1hkPTK4cY0dYIxDKGBCHrgyaDqE0u0" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is that when the image is rotated the width can be set to 100% and it takes who width of the parent (which is 200px) and the height is adjusted automatically.

Comment: did you try rotating the div instead?

Comment: I dot want to rotate the div. Need to rotate the inner image

Comment: then add `overflow:hidden` there as well

Comment: Still that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: not sure what result you're after to be honest

Comment: you cannot do this with rotation. Rotation is only a visual effect and cannot affect the dimension of elements

Comment: if you wanted it to still fill the div, then you need to resize the image so it has the correct height and width to do so once it is rotated - ie swap the height and width around from the original image - you may want to use something like object fit on the rotated image too so the aspect ratio is not messed up - https://jsfiddle.net/k5zq7vx3/